Probability of two independent random variables are equal decreases when they are more spread out
Let $X_{1},X_2\sim Bin(n,p)$ be iid binomial random variables. Then it is intuitive that $\mathbb P(X_1=X_2)$ decreases when $n$ increases (keeping $n$ fixes). However, it is not obvious to prove this rigorously. One way is to use characteristic function (see this post). The other way is to use normal approximation (but I am not sure how to make it rigorous, see here). These methods don't seem to generalize to other problems, like showing $\mathbb P(Bin(N,1-p)=Poi(c(1-p)))$ is increasing in $p$ keeping $N$ and $c$ fixed, or showing $\mathbb P(Hypergeometric(n,n-k,c)=Bin(n-k,p))$ increases when $k$ increases from $1$ to $n$ keeping $c,n,p$ fixed. I think the intuition is like when $p$ increases from zero to one, the binomial and the poisson both shift to left and are more and more concentrated. Is there a good approach?

Here is the motivation for this question:
I am interested in showing the convexity of $f(t)=\mathbb P(X+Y\ge N, X+Y'\ge N)$ where $X\sim Poi(at),Y, Y'\sim Poi(b-at)$. My approach is to consider a discrete version of  $f'(t)$. Let $X_k\sim Bin(k,p)$ and $Y_{n-k},Y_{n-k}'\sim Bin(n-k,p)$. Then maybe it reduces to showing $$g(k)=\mathbb P(X_k+Y_{n-k}\ge N , X_k+Y'_{n-k}\ge N)-\mathbb P(X_{k-1}+Y_{n-k+1}\ge N, X+Y'_{n-k+1}\ge N)$$ is increasing in $k$. I think we can rewrite $g(k)$ as follows. Sample $X_{k-1},Y_{n-k},Y_{n-k}'$ using the above notation and also $W,W'\sim Bernouli(p)$. Then
\begin{align*}
    g(k)&=\mathbb P(X_{k-1}+W+Y_{n-k}\ge N, X_{k-1}+W+Y_{n-k}'\ge N)-\mathbb P(X_{k-1}+W+Y_{n-k}\ge N, X_k+W'+Y'_{n-k}\ge N)\\ &= \mathbb P(X_{k-1}\ge\max(N-Y_{n-k}-W,N-Y'_{n-k}-W))-\mathbb P(X_{k-1}\ge\max(N-Y_{n-k}-W,N-Y'_{n-k}-W'))
\end{align*}
Let $A$ denote the first event and $B$ denote the second. Then $g(k)=\mathbb P(A)-\mathbb P(B)=\mathbb P(A\setminus B)-\mathbb P(B\setminus A)$.
If $A\setminus B$ occurs, then $X_{k-1}$ is less than either $N-Y_{n-k}-W$ or $N-Y_{n-k}'-W'$, but the former can't happen since $A$ occurs, so $X_{k-1}<N-Y_{n-k}'-W'$. But we also know $N-Y_{n-k}'-W\le X_{k-1}$. Since $N-Y_{n-k}'-W$ and $N-Y_{n-k}'-W'$ differ by at most one, we must have $W=1,W'=0$ and $X_{k-1}=N-Y_{n-k}'-1$. Since $N-Y_{n-k}'-1=X_{k-1}\ge N-Y_{n-k}-W=N-Y_{n-k}-1$, we also have $Y_{n-k}'\le Y_{n-k}$. So we've shown $$A\setminus B\Rightarrow W=1,W'=0,X_{k-1}=N-Y_{n-k}'-1,Y_{n-k}'\le Y_{n-k}$$ and the $\Leftarrow$ clearly holds.
Similarly, if $B\setminus A$ holds, then $N-Y_{n-k}'-W'\le X_{k-1}<N-Y_{n-k}'-W $, so we must have $W'=1,W=0$ and $X_{k-1}=N-Y_{n-k}'-1$. Also $X_{k-1}\ge N-Y_{n-k}-W=N-Y_{n-k}$, so $Y_{n-k}'+1\le Y_{n-k}$. In other words, $$B\setminus A\Rightarrow W=0,W'=1,X_{k-1}=N-Y_{n-k}'-1,Y_{n-k}'+1\le Y_{n-k}$$
and $\Leftarrow$ clearly holds.
Hence
\begin{align*}
    g(k)&=\mathbb P(A\setminus B)-\mathbb P(B\setminus A)\\&=\mathbb P(W=1,W'=0)\mathbb P(X_{k-1}=N-Y_{n-k}'-1,Y_{n-k}'\le Y_{n-k})\\&\quad\quad-\mathbb P(W=0,W'=1)\mathbb P(X_{k-1}=N-Y_{n-k}'-1,Y_{n-k}'+1\le Y_{n-k})\\ &=p(1-p)\mathbb P(X_{k-1}=N-Y_{n-k}'-1,Y_{n-k}=Y'_{n-k})
\end{align*}
so we need to show $\mathbb P(X_{k-1}=N-Y_{n-k}'-1,Y_{n-k}=Y'_{n-k})$ is increasing in $k$. We can condition out $\mathbb P(X_{k-1}=N-Y_{n-k}'-1)$ (which is the same as $\mathbb P(Bin(n-k-1,p)=N-1)$, so it is constant in $k$). Hence it suffices to show $\mathbb P(Y_{n-k}=Y_{n-k}'|Y_{n-k}'=N-X_{k-1}-1)$. It turns out the random variable $(Y_{n-k}'|Y_{n-k}'=N-X_{k-1}-1)$ has a hypergeometric distribution $hypergeometric(n-1,n-k,N-1)$, since we can compute its pdf  $$
   \frac{\mathbb P(Y_{n-k}'=t,X_{k}=N-1-t)}{\mathbb P(Bin(n-k-1)=t)}=\frac{\binom{n-k}{t}\binom{k-1}{N-1-t}}{\binom{n-1}{N-1}}
$$ after some cancellation, which also makes sense combinatorially in retrospect. So the task now is to show $$\mathbb P(Bin(n-k,p)=hypergeometric(n-1,n-k,N-1))$$ increases with $k$, which is true intuitively since when $k$ increases both distribution shift towards left and becomes more and more concentrated.

I don't think there is a closed form for even the PDF of the difference of two iid binomial distribution Bin(n,p) (when p is not 1/2).

What is exactly $Y'$ in $f(t)$? Is your main question to show the convexity of this function?

@Amir That is just for motivation, the main question is is described on the bounty notice.

(Partial answer)

Main answer.
One has :
$$
\begin{align}
\Bbb{P}(X_1 = X_2) &= \sum_k \Bbb{P}(X_1 = X_2 = k) \\
                   &= \sum_k \Bbb{P}(X_1 = k)\Bbb{P}(X_2 = k) & (1) \\
                   &= \sum_k \Bbb{P}(X_1 = k)^2 & (2)
\end{align}
$$
when $X_1$ and $X_2$ are $(1)$ independent and $(2)$ identical in addition. Closed forms might not always exist, but you can still study the final expression with respect to the parameters of $X_{1,2}$, at least asymptotically. Here are some tools and examples which may help you.

Some (maybe) useful tools.
All the techniques work in the same vein somehow, in that the summand is expressed differently in order to produce an easier summation, before coming back to the initial formulation. I listed below some ideas on how to rewrite the said summand in another manner.
Series and integral representations.
You can replace a term/factor by its series or integral representation, in order to apply further the binomial theorem afterwards for instance. In particular, the following integral representation (coming from Egorychev's method) is quite useful when dealing with factorials and binomial coefficients :
$$
\binom{n}{k} = \oint_C\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{2\pi i} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{k+1}}
\quad\&\quad
\frac{n^k}{k!} = \oint_C\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{2\pi i} \frac{e^{nz}}{z^{k+1}}
$$
where $C$ denotes the unit circle. By the way, note that ugly sums at first glance are often related to special functions or their generating functions, that is why it is worth taking a look at this side.
Differential equations and recurrence relations.
Let's recall that the quantity $\Bbb{P}(X_1 = X_2)$ depends on the different parameters of $X_1$ and $X_2$. If those are denoted by $\lambda,\mu,\ldots$, then you may differentiate the function $f(\lambda,\mu,\ldots) = \Bbb{P}(X_1 = X_2)$ in order to produce a differential equation, which might be easier to solve than the original summation. If the said parameters are discrete, then the function $f$ will satisfy a recurrence relation by analogy.
Z-transform and convolution theorem.
In the case where the sum can be recasted as a (discrete) convolution product, then you may apply the discrete analog of the convolution theorem, where the Laplace transform is replaced by the Z-transform, that is $\mathcal{Z}[x*y](z) = X(z)Y(z)$, where
$$
(x*y)(n) = \sum_{k\in\Bbb{Z}} x(k)y(n-k) \quad\text{and}\quad X(z) = \mathcal{Z}[x](z) = \sum_{k\in\Bbb{Z}} x(n)z^{-k}.
$$

Example 1.
Let's start with an easy example with $X_1 = \mathcal{Pois}(\lambda_1)$ and $X_2 = \mathcal{Pois}(\lambda_2)$. Then, one has :
$$
f(\lambda_1,\lambda_2) = \Bbb{P}(X_1 = X_2) = e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda_1\lambda_2)^k}{k!} = e^{\lambda_1\lambda_2 - \lambda_1 - \lambda_2}
$$
For example, when $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda$, one understands that the results increases (monotonically) when $\lambda > 1$, because $\partial_\lambda f(\lambda,\lambda) = 2(\lambda-1)e^{\lambda^2-2\lambda}$.
Example 2.
Now, let's take $X_1 = \mathcal{Pois}(\lambda)$ and $X_2 = \mathcal{Geom}(p)$, hence :
$$
f(\lambda,p) = \Bbb{P}(X_1 = X_2) = pe^{-\lambda} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}(1-p)^{k-1} = \frac{p}{p-1}e^{-\lambda p}
$$
This probability clearly decreases with $\lambda$. You can study its behaviour with respect to $p$ by computing $\partial_pf(\lambda,p)$ for instance.
Example 3.
When $X_1 \sim \mathcal{Bin}(n,p_1)$ and $X_2 \sim \mathcal{Bin}(n,p_2)$, we get :
$$
\begin{align}
f(n,p_1,p_2) &= \Bbb{P}(X_1 = X_2) \\
             &= (1-p_1)^n(1-p_2)^n \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2 x^k \\
             &= (1-p_1)^n(1-p_2)^n(1-x)^n P_n\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)
\end{align}
$$
with $x = \frac{p_1}{1-p_1}\frac{p_2}{1-p_2}$ and $P_n$ the $n^\mathrm{th}$ Legendre polynomial. It let you study this expression.
Example 4.
With $X_1 \sim \mathcal{Bin}(n,p)$ and $X_2 \sim \mathcal{Pois}(\lambda)$, one has :
$$
f(n,p,\lambda) = \Bbb{P}(X_1 = X_2) = e^{-\lambda}(1-p)^n \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{x^k}{k!},
$$
with $x = \lambda p(1-p)$. A closed form doesn't seem to exist. Bessel functions might be related to this expression because of the factor $k!^2$ in the denominator. Despite that, you can study the sign of the derivatives of $f$ or determine asymptotical behaviours.

Thanks for your answer. It seems the probability of two independent RVs are equal decreases when they are more spread out, but I am really bothered by the fact that there is no easy proof in lots of special cases. Say for example 3, do you have any idea how to show this decreases when n increases for fixed $p_1,p_2$? I wonder if there is any general theorem lurking behind.
